# div class name or change method?

Tags: jquery, html

I want add my page some div and another tags.I wanna give unique class name like that:

```
 dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var c = eval(msg.d);
                var html = ''; //'<tbody>';
                for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    var className = "questionContainer " + i;
                    html += "<div class=" + className + ">";
                    html += "<div class=question><b>Question" + (i + 1) + ":</b>" + c[i].Name + "?</div>";
                    html += "<div class=answers><ul>";
                    for (var j = 0; j < c[i].Choses.length; j++) {
                        html += "<li> <label><input type=radio name=q1" + i + i + "id=q1-a />" + c[i].Choses[j].Name + "</label></li>";
                    }
                    html += "</ul></div>";
                    html += "<div class=btnContainer><div class=prev></div><div class=next><a class=btnNext>Next &gt;&gt;</a></div> <div class=clear></div></div></div>";
                }
                html += '</div>';
                // $('#dataTable').empty();
                $('.as').append(html);

            }
        });
    });
</script>
<head>
    <body>
      <h1>jQuiz Demo Page</h1>
      <div class="as"></div>

    </body>
</head>
```

but my html show

```
 <div id="0" class="questionContainer" 0=""> like that how can I fixed?
```

space must have inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a space after the class name, and you need to put quotes round it in the next line...

```
var className = "questionContainer" + i;
html += "<div class='" + className + "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var className = "questionContainer"+ i +"";
```